# Ruby on Rails - one to one/many? bi-directional polymorphic with a twist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, one-to-many, polymorphic-associations, one-to-one

I'm working on a preexit disease registry, and I need some help on a new featur.

In the database, there are several tables responsible for different visits of a patient (call them V1, V2, V3). Different samples can be collected at a visit (stool, swab, blood, etc...). Each sample has a specific sample ID (string), and given a sample ID, I need to search through the sample table (bi-directional relationship), and find out which visit was the sample from, and which patient was the sample from.

Now, I have 2 ideas.

1. In order to keep track what sample it is, each visit table has a one-to-one reference to the specific sample (i.e. stool_sample, swab_sample), which is the unique id in the sample table. But in order to achieve bi-directional relationship (sample to visit during search), I need to make a polymorphic relationship from the sample table. This method require me to store id on both side, which generally feels like a bad idea.
2. The send method is simply doing a polymorphic relationship on the sample table, and add the sample type as an extra column on the table. However, this requires me to hard code the sample type upon creation/update on the view page.

I'm just wondering if anyone have any suggestions on these? or is there a better solutions? Preferably with sample code since I'm quite new to this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that a sample should belong to a visit (polymorphic to permit the varying visit types/tables).  No self-referencing or hard-coding needed.  You can also make an abstract `Visit` class to keep this DRY:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  has_one :sample, as: :visit
  belongs_to :patient
end

class VisitOne < Visit
end

class VisitTwo < Visit
end

class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :visit, polymorphic: true
  delegate :patient, to: :visit
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visit_ones
  has_many :visit_twos
end
```

You can now find the `Visit` and `Patient` based on the `Sample`, as well as the `Sample` and `Patient` based on the `Visit`.  You can also track the various `Visit` types for each `Patient`.  The Sample 'type' (*wince*, try to use another term that is more accurate) can simply be stored as a text field on `Sample` - if you don't want to hard-code these types as an enumeration in your code, you can make a table to hold your sample types, and have the `Sample` belong_to a `SampleType`.

Comment: I'm just wondering how could I create/update it in the view page? and how do I define the sample type? Can you give me some sample code, thank you

Comment: By the way, I'm using simple_form

Comment: @hook38 asking a modeling/architectural question is one thing - asking for a prototype application is quite another ;).  Please make a best effort, and post back if you are having a specific problem.